# local outlier factor real world example

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have studied local outlier factor but I  would like to know how we use it in real world example? I mean is it used alone for classification or it works with other classification algorithms?
is it part of data preprocessing? to explain more my question suppose I have a data-set and I would like to classify it but there is outliers so shall I apply local outlier factor and it will remove outliers so I can apply my classification algorithm on it? or it classified by local outlier factor

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local Outlier Factor value is a commonly used anomaly detection tool. It **takes a local approach to better detect outliers about their neighbors, whereas a global strategy, might not be the best detection for datasets that fluctuate in density.**

While a LOF value of 1 or less is a good indicator of an inlier, we are here to calculate and probably remove outliers or anomalies.
Do you have a tight, clean, and uniform dataset? Then a LOF value of 1.05 could be an outlier.
Do you have a sparse dataset, varying in density, with many local fluctuations specific to that local cluster? Then a LOF value of 2 could still be an inlier.